# Understanding require_tree load order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Dear all I have the following folders angular_components

[image: Directory Structure]

Now for loading this files inside this folder I wrote

```
//= require_tree ./angular-components
```

The way files are loaded are

```
<script src="/assets/angular-components/mapAutoComplete/autoCompleteAddressApp.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-components/mapAutoComplete/directive/controllers/googleAddressSuggestion.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-components/mapAutoComplete/directive/googleAddressSuggestion.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-components/mapAutoComplete/services/locationDataService.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-components/stripePayment/lib/angularPayment.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-components/stripePayment/services/stripeService.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/angular-components/stripePayment/stripePaymentApp.js?body=1"></script>
```

In the mapAutoComplete directory the file in the root folder autoCompleteAddressApp.js loaded before the other file however in the stripe payment the stripePaymentApp.js which is in the root folder loaded at the end. Why this is happening? How can I make sure in both cases the root file loaded before the child directory file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is `require_tree` loads the files or folders alphabetically whether it is a file or folder. One a way of solving your problem is individually loading the file without using `require_tree`. Another way you can achieve your goal is by adding `_` underscore before the file you want to load first. Because `require_tree` will load the file prefixed with underscore before the other files. So in your case your directory structure would like following

[image: Updated dir structure]